# vs code snippets text alignment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, code-snippets

I am using c# and VS2012 and am trying to produce a code snippet to insert a module header comment block along the following lines:

```
    /*-------------------------------------------------------
     * Module Name - 
     * Parameters:
     * Returns: 
     * etc.
     *--------------------------------------------------------*/
```

The intention is that it should be indented in line with the module definition (2 tabs).

The first line indents fine but all subsequent lines are inserted at the LH margin. I have tried both spaces and tabs but the effect is the same. This is slightly strange because if entering normally and hitting Enter at the end of the first line, the editor automatically inserts a correctly-aligned asterisk.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how such alignment could be achieved by a code snippet, please?

Comment: Show us your snippet file.